# Close AutoCompleteTextView dropdown

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, dropdown

I've got an `AutoCompleteTextView` with a dropdown list. How can I close dropdown programmatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `dismissDropDown()` to close the dropdown.